# Open Ibuffer selected buffer in other existing window

Tags: window-splitting, ibuffer

I tried everything but again I'm hitting a wall here. I have one frame split in the middle with a vertical line giving me a window left and right. Now I have Ibuffer open in the left window and I just want to press a key and the selected buffer should open in the right window WITHOUT opening another window. Whatever I do I either get Ibuffer to open the selected buffer in it's own buffer (pressing Return for example) or getting it to open it new window or frame. It seems impossible for it to open it in the already opened window on the right. I'm not a coder so I can't help myself using some lisp.

Comment: `o` = `visit-buffer-other-window`  If that doesn't work, perhaps your other window/buffer is *strongly* dedicated?  Instead of using what everyone likes to recommend -- e.g., `C-h m` to read the available commands for a given mode/buffer that has focus, I like to actually see the source code and find out the name of the variable and what it entails.  So, I like `M-x find-variable RET ibuffer-mode-map RET` because I already investigated the name of the variable I am interested in.

Comment: Yeah, I know about o, despite the name suggesting otherwise it opens a new window no matter what. Strongly dedicated? I use `(setq split-height-threshold 5000)` but you can reproduce my problem even on a vanilla emacs. The only difference to my config is that o opens the new window for selected buffer elsewhere. Ibuffer should use the existing other window, not a new one by splitting and not itself.

Comment: Your other window that you want to target may be strongly dedicated -- you can check it out with `window-dedicated-p`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html  If it is strongly dedicated because something you are using set it that way, then a new window will likely be created and result in the behavior you wish to change.  You may wish to try with `emacs -q` and just open ibuffer with a second window and see if the behavior is the same.  If it is dedicated, then you can turn it off -- see the link to the manual above.

Comment: As stated in my last comment the behaviour is also in vanilla emacs (meaning -q): o always opens a new window and return always uses it's own window. I need neither. Is every buffer by default a dedicated buffer? Would be the only explaination that it also happens in vanilla emacs.

Comment: Neither emacs -Q nor emacs with my custom init.el shows the behaviour that that you mention. I open some files (find-file) then C-x 3 to get the windows configuration. I call ibuffer in any window. Select a buffer and hit o... emacs version is 25.1.50.1

Comment: I use GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2016-09-17. Sounds like what I do. If you switch back to your ibuffer window, select a different buffer and hit o again it opens the buffer in the other window without opening another window? 25.1.50? This version is older than the release version 25.1 isn't it? What OS do you use? Maybe it's a bug. That would expain. I might try a 24.5 version later.

Comment: Just tried GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) of 2015-04-11. This one works as expected, when using -q. So is it bug introduced between 25.1.50 and 25.1.1?

Comment: This is currently annoying me as well on Emacs 25.1. Exactly as described: with two windows open and ibuffer in one of them, `o` splits the other window rather than using it. Once there are three windows, using  `o` in ibuffer alternates between using the other two windows.

Comment: Same thing happens with a dired view trying to visit files in another window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs more investigation on negative side-effects, but setting `display-buffer-base-action` to `display-buffer-use-some-window` seem to work. Found hint to it on 
https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/24zu2a/how_do_i_stop_emacs_from_taking_over_my_split/

Using the mentioned variable with the hook from glucas mentioned below seems to work and limits possible side effects to ibuffer. It's a workaround, but better than nothing.

Comment: To whom who gave me -1, well first I would like an expaination why my post is not useful, since it does what I need, despite some possible negative side-effects and second do you have a better solution? I would be glad to hear about it.

Comment: This works for me. For now I'm doing it locally for ibuffer using a hook: `(add-hook 'ibuffer-mode-hook (lambda () (setq-local display-buffer-base-action '(display-buffer-use-some-window))))`

Comment: Glucas, thanks for that hook. It works as expected. I hope this whole workaround is not needed anymore anytime soon but as of emacs 25.2.1 this problem still exists.

Comment: @glucas I added your script but it did not work :-(